# xCode iOS - NSFetchedResultsController multiple rows in single UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

i have a "table data" like this

```
Date     User    
10/10/10 USER1 (This will go in the first cell)
10/10/10 USER2  "

12/10/10 USER1 (This will go in the second cell)
12/10/10 USER2  "
12/10/10 USER3  "
```

My CoreDataObject have this two columns and i query my CoreData to retrieve all of them. Now, i should display this information (divided per date) each for table view Cell (as described before).

Usually i have even implemented cellForRowAtIndexPath with:

```
Item *turnoAutomotive = (Item*)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

This grab a single data and "put" it in a single cell. But now i have "multiple" data to put in a single cell. How to implement it?

Comment: You can use a section to show this

Comment: How ? Could you show me a little example ?

Comment: you can see the contact app

Comment: what is contact app ? I need to grab multiple Core Data rows and place them in a sigle IUTableViewCell. For example: Core data (for an entity) could have 50 rows, and my table view will have 5 rows (10 Core Data Object Rows => 1 UITableViewCell). Its a little different from divide table view in seciton.

Comment: The problem that i have here is that for each section it return the number of rows, instead the number of rows should be even ONE. For example for 10/10/10 it get me 2 rows and for 12/10/10 i got 3 rows.